# Why are some windows installers using the R drive?

Tags: windows-7

My system has few drive letters mounted using Ext2Fsd, namely letters R and H, for root and home of my Linux install, respectively.

I recently figured out why I have weirdly named folders in Linux's root directory:

Some MS installers, namely offline .NET 4.5.1 installer, decided to put it's cache in the root of the R drive. Not C, or D. Not even H, just R.

I assume it's specific to the R letter, because H is untouched, despite 
being the same kind of drive. I didn't try changing drive letters to confirm.

This is at most annoying, but why it does that? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: It does erase them afterwards, though. So it must have been an interrupted install.

Answer (score -1):

I have not confirmed this, but It seems it uses the drive with the most free space. At least It overlapped this time, and seems logical thing to do.